Bring apex class variable value to VF page action function oncomplete not working
Below is my code:
Apex:
public class EmailTemplate_Lookup {
    public String IdChosen {get; set;}
    public String faqId { get; set; } 
    public String response { get; set; }
    
    public List<emailTemplateWrapper> recordsList{get;set;}
    
    public EmailTemplate_Lookup (){
        recordsList=new List<emailTemplateWrapper>();
        recordsList.add(new emailTemplateWrapper(0));
        response= this.response;
    }
    
    public class emailTemplateWrapper{
        public String emailTemplateName{get;set;} 
        public String emailTemplateId{get;set;}
        public String frequency{get;set;}
        public integer counter{get;set;} //to store rowindex
        public emailTemplateWrapper( integer count){
            frequency='Weekly';
            counter=count;
        } 
    }
    
    public void getEmailTemplateBody() { 
        faqId = '';
        String body = '';
        faqId  = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        
        if(IdChosen != ''){
            EmailTemplate template = [SELECT HtmlValue, Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Id = :IdChosen LIMIT 1]; 
            
            if (template != null) { 
                if (template.HtmlValue != null) { 
                    body =  template.HtmlValue; 
                } else if (template.Body != null) { 
                    body =  template.Body; 
                } 
            }  
        }else{
            response = 'template';
        }
        
        
        List<FAQ__kav> faqtobeUpdate = [SELECT ID,Email_Template_Content__c FROM FAQ__kav WHERE ID=:faqId AND PublishStatus = 'Draft'];
        if(faqtobeUpdate.size()>0){
            faqtobeUpdate[0].Email_Template_Content__c = body; 
            try { 
                update faqtobeUpdate; 
                response = 'success';
                
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                System.debug('Error saving record: ' + e.getMessage()); 
                response = 'failed';
            }  
        }else{
            response = 'draft';
        }
    }
}

vf page:
<apex:page controller="EmailTemplate_Lookup" lightningStylesheets="true" id="wpage"> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    
    var templatenameid; 
    function openTemplatePopUp(field) { 
        var anchortagid = field.id; 
        var rowindex = anchortagid.substring(9, 10); 
        templatenameid = 'wpage:form1:pgb1:pgbt1:' + rowindex + ':Template'; 
        if (field != null) { 
            field.href = "JavaScript:openLookup('/_ui/common/data/LookupPage?lkfm=editPage&lknm='+templatenameid+'&lkrf=&epf=1&lktp=00X',670,'1','&lksrch=' + escapeUTF(getElementByIdCS(templatenameid).value.substring(0, 80)))"; 
        } 
        
    } 
    function callApex() { 
        var templateIdField = document.getElementById('wpage:form1:pgb1:pgbt1:0:Template_lkid').value; 
        submitActionFunction(templateIdField); 
        console.log(templateIdField); 
    } 
    
    function ShowSuccessToast() {
        alert("{!response}");
        var messageres = "{!response}";
        if(messageres == 'template'){
            sforce.one.showToast({
                "title": "Success",
                "message": "Please select a email template",
                "type": "error"
            });
        }else if (messageres == 'success'){
            sforce.one.showToast({
                "title": "Success",
                "message": "Record updated successfully",
                "type": "success"
            });
        }else if(messageres == 'draft'){
            sforce.one.showToast({
                "title": "Error",
                "message": "Article should be in Draft status",
                "type": "error"
            });
        }
        
    }
    
    </script>
    <style>
        body .pbHeader ~ .pbBody, .slds-vf-scope .pbHeader ~ .pbBody {
        padding-top: 0;
        margin-top: .75rem;
        width: 350px;
        }
        
        .myCustomMessage .message {
        background: none  !important;
        border: none !important;
        }
    </style>
    <apex:form id="form1" > 
        
        <apex:pageBlock title="" id="pgb1" >
            
            <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>
            
            <apex:actionFunction name="submitActionFunction"  oncomplete="ShowSuccessToast();"  action="{!getEmailTemplateBody}" rerender="form1"> 
                <apex:param name="inputTextField" value="" assignTo="{!IdChosen}"/> 
            </apex:actionFunction>
            
            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!recordsList}" var="rec" id="pgbt1" styleclass="" style="background-color: white;width: 100px"> 
                <apex:column headerValue="Select Email Template" > 
                    <br/>
                    <div class="slds-form-element" style="background-color: white;"> 
                        <apex:inputhidden value="{!rec.emailTemplateId}" id="Template_lkid" />                 
                        <apex:inputhidden value="{!rec.emailTemplateName}" id="Template_lkold" /> 
                        
                        <span class="lookupInput" style="background-color: white;"> 
                            <apex:inputText value="{!rec.emailTemplateName}" onchange="getElementByIdCS('wpage:form1:pgb1:pgbt1:{!rec.counter}:Template_lkid').value=''; " id="Template"/>                   
                            <a title="Email Template Lookup (New Window)" tabindex="4" onclick="setLastMousePosition(event),openTemplatePopUp(this)" id="Template_{!rec.counter}_lkwgt" >
                                <img title="Email Template Lookup (New Window)" onmouseover="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';this.className = 'lookupIconOn';" onmouseout="this.className = 'lookupIcon';this.className = 'lookupIcon';" onfocus="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';" onblur="this.className = 'lookupIcon';" class="lookupIcon" alt="Email Template Lookup (New Window)" src="/s.gif" />
                            </a>
                        </span>
                    </div> 
                    <br/>
                    <apex:commandButton onclick="callApex();" value="Submit" styleClass="slds-button slds-button_brand" rerender="form1" ></apex:commandButton>
                   
                </apex:column> 
            </apex:pageblockTable>
            
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>

here I want to display toast message based on the response value in apex class.
but alert("{!response}") gives null value.
Is there any issue in my code to pass value from apex to vf page.
Please help e to resolve this. I have tried many ways already.
Thank You

Not quite sure about a way around this, but it's happening because the {!response} is only getting evaluated once (when Salesforce transforms the VF markup into HTML on the initial page load) when response does not have any value. Maybe try bringing the <script> tag into the <apex:form> so it too will have a chance to be re-rendered?

Oh yes its working now

Thank you so much

Visualforce isn't what ends up getting sent to your browser when you view the page in Salesforce.
When a request comes in to view a page, Salesforce takes your VF and does an evaluation pass. Variables are gathered and substituted in where you use merge expressions, methods get called and their return values put in place, etc... This gets turned into HTML, which is then sent to your browser.
Because of that, there's no "dynamic"/"responsive" updating. Since your response value is null when the page first loads, it will always be null unless you:

Do an entire page refresh (via a POST that includes the current viewstate for your controller or extension)
Do a partial page refresh and have your <script>...</script> inside the block(s) that are targeted by that partial page refresh

With that in mind, the simplest way to "fix" this would be to move your js into the <apex:form id="form1"> tag.

Thank you for the guidance . Its working now
